# Progress indicator with WP8 (MVVM) and asynchronous web service

Tags: c#, mvvm, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I'm a newbie in async programming. 
I'm creating WP8 application.

**What I would like to have**

I would like to show list of e.g. news. When button is tapped:

1. there should appear proggress indicator,
2. data should be downloaded and displayed,
3. progress indicator should dissapear.

---

**What I have so far:**

Method in referenced webservice:

```
void GetNewsAsync() 
{
    //...
}
```

Two methods in viewModel:

```
public void GetNewsFromService()
{
    //call webservice
    //...
    client.GetNewsCompleted += client_GetNewsCompleted;
    client.GetNewsAsync(startDate);
}

void client_GetNewsCompleted(object sender, GetNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//save result from webservice to db
//update viewmodel property
//...
}
```

OnClick method in view for button "sync":

```
void appBarSyncButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TurnOnProgressBar();
    _viewModel.GetNewsFromService();
    //TurnOffProgressBar();
}
```

---

Everything is working (web service is called, result data is saved, list is updating, but...

**How to redesign this code to inform view in order to hide progress indicator (when all work is completed)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client_GetNewsCompleted` should assign a public property like `Completed` to true. Following that, it would be more MVVM, if you had a property like IsInProgress that you manage completely in your ViewModel - set to true in `GetNewsFromService` and false in `client_GetNewsCompleted`. Then simply bind ProgressIndicator.Visibility to that property (using converter).

Comment: lisp has a very good solution, I always use a base class on all my ViewModels that has a property IsBusy (bool) for that purpose. When needed just set to true or false and your View can use this to toggle visibility